# $|sin(ax)|\le a|sin(x)|$ where $ a > 0 $ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have already proved for $x \in \mathbb{R},\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ that

$|\sin((n+1)x)|=|\sin(nx)\cos x+\cos(nx)\sin(x)|\le|\sin(nx)|\cos(x)|+|\cos(nx)||\sin(x)|\\\le|\sin(nx)|+|\sin(x)|\le n|\sin(x)|+|\sin(x)|=(n+1)|\sin(x)|$

Is that true for $ a > 0 $ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$?
$$|sin(ax)|\le a|sin(x)|$$
I guess that the statement is correct because $a$ is positive but I'm struggling at this point. I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: What happens with $a = 1/2$ and $ x = \pi$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ be any number such that $\sin(x)=0$. Choose $a>0$ such that $\sin(ax)\neq 0$. Then

$$\lvert\sin(ax)\rvert>0=a\lvert\sin(x)\rvert,$$

thus your statement is not true in general.

Answer (score 0):

As remarked in comments and in the other answer, you need to at least to check when $sin(x)=0$. The set of zeros of $\sin$ is $\pi \mathbb{Z}$.
So if you want your inequality, you need to have $\sin(ax)=0$ for those $x$, i.e.
$$ax\in \pi \mathbb{Z}$$
for all $x\in \pi \mathbb{Z}$.
That implies that $a\in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $a>0$, and since you show it with $a\in \mathbb{N}^*$, you have exactly the $a$ for which it works : $a\in \mathbb{N}^*$.